# How delete special characters at beginning of sentence with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have sentences in Python strings like this:

```py
string_1 = "a) This is sentence 1"
string_2 = "oThis is sentence 2" # ("o" is a bullet point format in word)
string_3 = "- This is sentence 3"
```

I would like to delete these characters at the beginning with regex.
Expected output:

```py
string_1 = "This is sentence 1"
string_2 = "This is sentence 2"
string_3 = "This is sentence 3"
```

How can I do this with regex ?

Comment: So ensure the first capital letter is the first char?

Comment: `a` and `o` is not special chars in the regex world. What do you mean by "special"? Please clarify the problem, and show your pattern + code to see where you are stuck.

Comment: [`^.*?(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/vv4kRX/4) ?

Comment: I would like to ignore/delete all type of bullet points. This can work \w[.)]\s* but not sure for all bullet point.

Comment: When asked for clarification please edit your question rather than elaborate in comments. Questions should be self-contained and not all readers read all comments, and nor should they be expected to do so. Your question is ambiguous and your comment is vague about "bullet points". `"oThis is..."` is certainly not a bullet point. You need to state your question precisely, something like, "Remove all characters that precede the first capital letter in the string. If the string contains no capital letters return an empty string", though I don't know if that is in fact what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple example which deletes all characters at the start of the string that are not a capital letter.

```py
import re

string_1 = "a) This is sentence 1"

string_1 = re.sub("^[^A-Z]+", "", string_1)

print(string_1)

# "This is sentence 1"
```

- `^` means assert start of the string
- `[^A-Z]+` means match one or more characters that are not the capital letters A-Z.